# AWS: How to route to autoscaling group based on URL pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

Our app has independent clusters of boxes running on Amazon Web Services. I need to send http requests to different clusters based on the URL. For example, http://api.mydomain.com/foo should go to the "foo" cluster, and http://api.mydomain.com/bar should go to the "bar" cluster.

I don't see anything in the elastic load balancer or Route 53 that will do it.

(The obvious thing is to have separate subdomains, but that's difficult for this app. We want to stick with just the "api" subdomain because the cluster configuration may change in the future.)

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported by the load balancer. Using subdomains does work if you want to use the existing load balancer.

If you need more features, you could configure your own using a software load balancer running on top of an ec2 instance. Not likely to be as cost effective however.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using ELB. Use Netscaler EC2 or HAProxy EC2 in your AWS environment to achieve this. NetScaler is available in AWS marketplace.